# Change content with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to update the content in a span tag when a user click on a button. The span tag has a class called `fa_button_id_counter` and a `id` with the post id. It should be simple, but I can't make it work. Any suggestions?

**view file:**

```
<a class="like_button fa_button active" href="#<%= p.id %>" id="<%= p.id %>">FA</a>
<span class="fa_button_id_counter" id="<%= p.id %>">+<%= p.likes.count %></span>
```

**.js file:**

```
$ ->
  $(".like_button").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault();
    id = $(this).attr('href')
    $(".fa_button_id_counter" + id).html "change to this"
```

Comment: Are your #ids numeric? html ids can't start with numbers.

Comment: Yes, they are numbers. I changed the id to `id="f<%= p.id %>"`, and it worked (because I put a char infront of the p.id)! Thanks alot! But, why cant id be numbers?

Comment: If it's HTML5, I don't think that the numbers restrictions apply anymore; http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/html5-id-class

Comment: use `.html()` or `.text()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id`s can't start with numbers. Gotta start with `a-zA-Z`.

To answer the question:

```
$(".fa_button_id_counter" + id).html('+'+(parseInt($(".fa_button_id_counter" + id).html(),10)+1))
```

`parseInt` takes a string and parses out a number. If `"+8"` is given, the number `8` will come out. However, you need to be careful to always provide the second parameter, `base`, set to `10`. Otherwise javascript will try to guess the base for you. If the input is `015`, the output will be `13`, because it is guessing that your number is in base 8.

**edit**: Thanks `mu is too short` and `vol7ron`: Numeric ids are allowed if you change your doctype to `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the id to `id="f<%= p.id %>"`, and it works now :)

Comment: That's not entirely true: ["Previous versions of HTML placed greater restrictions on the content of ID values (for example, they did not permit ID values to begin with a number)."](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

Comment: Well, until the implementation OP is testing on matches the spec, the spec isn't worth much.

Comment: @JoeFrambach: the problem wasn't the numbers the problem is the Doctype and the OP should change the doctype to just `<!DOCTYPE html>` so that HTML5 is used